Taking an older commit from the git history and applying all changes that happened in the meantime
I've deleted some files in our git repository and moved on with a new technology. Now it's time to go back to the "old" state and kind of get rid of the new technology.
Therefore I need to take the last version/commit from the git history, apply all changes that happened in the meantime, but exclude the new technology code.
Is this possible?
Example timeline/git history:

1 - apply some changes to old tech stack
2 - change to new tech stack and delete old tech stack
3 - make some changes to the new tech stack
4 - ...
5 - ...
6 - ...

Now would be the time to get back to the old tech stack (#1 in the example above) and apply all the changes except #2 from the example (the actual deletion).
This should then become the new version for HEAD.
Is this possible?
If so, how could I do that?
I tried (commit hash refers to the numbers in the example above):

git checkout -b 2~1
(~1 to get the one version before this commit - that's my assumption at least)

git revert 2~1

git reset --hard 1


Many thanks in advance!
robert

Sounds like a candidate for interactive rebasing to me. Also sounds like you should have separate branches for some of this...

It was not clear initially that we would need to go back to the old tech stack, therefore not label or branch has been created.

Well it's easy to create a new branch from any given commit. It's not clear at the moment whether you've literally got a single commit that does all of step 2 - if you have, that's going to be harder to work with. You might want to use interactive rebasing just to split that into multiple commits first, then (possibly on a different branch) take only some of those commits.

Thanks a lot again for your advice! I'm currently giving it a try, but as it's my first time using it, it takes some attempts ;-)

It sounds like you want to "undo" the changes of "2". In that case, a simple git revert 2 should suffice. No need to rebase, no need to checkout and reset. Just create a revert commit and you're done.

Update:
As it was only about a managable amount of files I copied them over from the old version (#1 in the example above), knowing that I will loose all the git history.
Thanks for all your inputs - issue solved!
